# Is there any alternative to Sage Evolution's way to backup & restore databases

Tags: sql-server, performance, backup, optimization, restore

I am currently working on a handful of web apps that work in coherence with our **Sage 200 (Evolution) database.**

However, one problem that we have noticed at the moment is the ability to backup and restore databases (*either through the sage interface or through the server itself*)

Obviously, only the database admin can back up through the server and only users with admin tools on Sage can do so on the sage interface. However the backup and restore process is becoming a bit tedious from the user perspective.

I just wanted to find out If there are **any alternatives to these methods that the users will make things easier for users.**

I was thinking that a feature in a web app would suffice, but I'm sure it would be a tedious task to try and diagnose what the functions are actually doing when they backup and restore entire databases.

If anyone has any suggestions or methods they have used before, please feel free to assist! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you considered [ola hallengren](https://ola.hallengren.com/) scripts? Just configure a couple of jobs and forget.

Comment: How often are you restoring the database? There are definitely a number of alternatives for backing it up such as Ola's scripts mentioned by McNets, or by setting up a maintenance plan, but are you guys routinely restoring the database and if so, why?